# What is ta.sma doing when na value in the source

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

program 1:

```
    rrr = ta.sma(close > 0 ? close : na, 20)
    fff = ta.sma(close < 0 ? close : na, 20)
```

program 2:

```
    var rrr = 0.0
    var fff = 0.0

    for i = 0 to 19
        if close[i] > 0
            rrr := rrr + close[i] / 20

    for i = 0 to 19
        if close[i] < 0
            fff := fff + close[i] / 20
```

I thought program 1 and 2 should come out the same result but not.
Is there something about ta.sma function which I am not awared of?

TIA

Comment: Why are you using `var`?

Answer (score 0):

Your script will be executed on each bar. Every time it will be a new execution. If you use the `var` keyword, that variable will keep its value between each execution. So, it will have history.

Remove the `var` keyword and it will be good (for the `rrr`).

For the `fff`, your own calculation will result in `na`.

Also, `if close[i] < 0` does not make any sense as the price won't be a negative value.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

r = ta.sma(close > 0 ? close : na, 20)
f = ta.sma(close < 0 ? close : na, 20)

rr = 0.0
ff = 0.0

for i = 0 to 19
    rr := rr + close[i] / 20

for i = 0 to 19
    ff := ff + close[i] / 20

plot(r, color=color.green)
plot(rr, color=color.blue)

plot(f, color=color.red)
plot(ff, color=color.orange)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you vitruvius,

yes, put "var" is not right.

Could you try to replace "close" by other indicator output has a negative value,
for example CCI indicator as the source. Thank you.